# Use *page-level* scrollbars to scroll a DIV (whose height to set to visible area)

Tags: html, css

Here's an ugly image showing what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I need to use the page scrollbars to scroll a DIV (whose height to set to visible area).

[image: screenshot]

Is this even possible in pure html5/CSS, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about framing your div out with a stack of fixed position border elements?  Something like this:

```
<!-- don't forget to declare a doctype -->
<body>
    <!-- leave these empty -->
    <div id="frameTop"></div>
    <div id="frameBottom"></div>
    <div id="frameLeft"></div>
    <div id="frameRight"></div>

    <!-- put stuff in these -->
    <div id="top">Content here</div>
    <div id="content">
        <h3>Page title</h3>
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">Tabs</div>
</body>
```

Set borderTop to have a bottom border style, borderBottom to have a top border style, then borderLeft and borderRight have a solid background color to hide the border lines at the corners.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/pns7s55f/)

---

**Edit:** I [found another method](http://css-tricks.com/body-border/) that might be preferable.  The HTML is certainly cleaner.  Instead of using empty divs for frameTop, frameBottom, etc, use css psuedo elements on body:before and body:after.  Then your HTML looks more like this:

```
<body>

    <div id="top">Content here</div>

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tab" class="radioTab" checked="checked" />
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Tab title</h3>
            <p>Text here.</p>
        </div>
        <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tab" class="radioTab" />
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Tab title 2</h3>
            <p>Different text here.</p>
        </div>
        <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
    </div>

</body>
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/pns7s55f/4/) for the CSS that makes it work.  I was a little lazy with the margin definitions in that fiddle, but it works well enough for a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

I made a more complete jsfiddle that illustrates how to fake the borders that you need for the design.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tkt7tmop/)

Note the extra padding on the top and bottom of the content div, and the use of background colors and borders to it seem like the interior box is it's own area. The orange sides actually scroll with the rest of it, and the top and bottom orange parts are attached to the header and footer.

```
html, body{
background-color:orange;
margin:0;padding:0;
}

header{
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
background-color:orange;
}

footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
background-color:orange;
}

header section, footer section{
background-color:#fff;
height:30px;
}

header .frame{
border-bottom:1px solid #222;
margin:0 30px 0 30px;
height:30px;
}

footer .frame{
border-top:1px solid #222;
margin:0 30px 0 30px;
height:30px;
}

.content{
background-color:#fff;
border-right:1px solid #222;
border-left:1px solid #222;
min-height:100%;
margin:0 30px 0 30px;
    padding:60px 24px;
}
```

Edit: Just noticed your footer is a little different, but you can adjust this to get that effect.

Answer (score 0):

theres a few ways to achieve that effect, since you're asking for a scrolling div, thats what ill do:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3z4oc6/)**

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    overflow: scroll;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>some content</div>
<nav>buttons</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as shown in the screenshot, I'd like to have/use the **page-level** scrollbar, not a div-specific scrollbar (I know how to have the later effect, but not the first one)

Comment: So then youd want to use `height:auto` on the div and `position:fixed` on the nav. the issue being that technically the div is larger than the viewport. [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3z4oc6/1/)

Comment: My apologies, as I said in title, the DIV's height is set to visible area (that's part of the design requirements :(), so I can't set it to auto. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: with those constraints technically no, there is no way to do that. The thing is though, with the div at 100% width and height there is no way to discern between the div scrollbar and the browser one. Since the browser one is basically just the body element scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to acheive this effect would be to give the tabs div at the bottom a fixed position. So that might look something like:

```
<div>Content Here. Lots perhaps.</div>

<ul class="nav-tabs>
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>
```

and the css would be

```
.nav-tabs {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    Height: 2em;
}
.nav-tabs li {
    float: left;
}
```

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9t05oey/). The scrollbar that appears is for the page, not the div, which is what you are wanting. Basically, the scroll bar for the page will appear if you have enough content, just like you would expect for any page. It's just that the navigation tabs always appear at the bottom of the page, no matter where you scroll to.

Comment: That's precisely what I did. But then, how to make the page-level scrollbars appreas (instead of having the DIV-level scbollars shown by playing with the css overflow)??

Comment: My apologies as well. As I said in title, the DIV's height is set to visible area (that's part of the design requirements :(), so I can't set it to auto (which is set implicitly AFAIK)

Comment: That's fine, you don't need to set the div to auto. This will work fine. Just give it a padding at the bottom that is equal to the height of the nav element.